# C++ how to load a 16bit TIFF file in a container to perform math operations on its data?

Tags: c++, csv, bitmap, tiff

I have writtent a small C++ console application with code::blocks that loads
an array of values from a CSV file, performs a special "inverted" random dithering on the values, and exports the result as a PBM file (a bitmap).

The density of black pixels on the final PBM picture depends on 3 independent variables: "Reflectance of the white", "Reflectance of the black", and the values of the CSV.

**The reason I use a CSV file is because I don't know how I can directly load a TIFF file into my script.** The values of my file "wall.csv" are produced by a python script that transforms any tiff file in a csv...

**Could you please check my code and advise for a solution to load a TIFF and detect automatically the size of the image in pixels?
The variables `colo` and `lines` define the size of the image contained as ASCII data in the CSV...
And the image values are loaded in the `vector <float> CSV`**

What library would you use to load the tiff?

Thanks!

**code:**

```
#include <deque>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

deque <float> CSV;          // CSV input values, "PHOTOMETRY"
deque <float> RND;          // will contain random values from 0.0 to 1.0

int   colo   = 0;           // variables inputed
int   lines  = 0;           // lines
float YBK    = 0;           // Reflectance White
float YW     = 0;           // Reflectance Black

float Lmax   = 0;           // variables to be computed
float Lmin   = 10000000;    // arbitrarily high value
float NBK    = 0;           // will contain a normalized Black value
float NW     = 1;           // normalized white value
float CRATIO = 0;           // Black to White dynamic ratio
float LRATIO = 0;           // Lowest to Highest pixel value dynamic ratio

float Z      = 0;           // processing variables
float X      = 0;
float aBK    = 0;           // computed density of black at each pixel
float vRND   = 0;           // random value container
float IO     = 0;

int main(){

cout << "please put a file named wall.csv" << endl << "in the same forler as this executable" << endl << endl;
cout << "how many:" << endl << "columns does the CSV has?" << endl;
cin  >> colo;
cout << "lines   does the CSV has?" << endl;
cin  >> lines;
cout << "reflectance of the WHITE (CIE Y)?" << endl;
cin  >> YW;
cout << "reflectance of the BLACK (CIE Y)?" << endl;
cin  >> YBK;

NBK    = YBK / YW;      // normalized BK
CRATIO = NW / NBK;      // correction Ratio
int C  = lines * colo;  // cells

cout << endl << "   there are: "               << colo   << "  columns";
cout << endl << "   and      : "               << lines  << "  lines " ;
cout << endl << "   that makes "               << C      << " cells " << endl;
cout << endl << "   correction ratio is: " << CRATIO << endl << endl;

///_____ IMPORT THE PHOTOMETRIC DATA

cout << "...importing the photometric data" << endl;

float x = 0;     // a variable that will contain a value from the file

    ifstream ifs ("wall.csv");

    char dummy;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i){
        for (int i = 0; i < colo; ++i){
            ifs >> x;

            if (x > Lmax) {
                Lmax = x;     // determines the highest pixel value
            }
            if (x < Lmin) {
                Lmin = x;     // determines the lowest  pixel value
            }

            CSV.push_back(x);

            // So the dummy won't eat digits
            if (i < (colo - 1))
                ifs >> dummy;
    }}

    ifstream ifs_close();
    LRATIO = Lmax / Lmin;

cout << "...photometric data imported"    << endl;
cout << endl << "   maximum Luminance  is: " << Lmax;
cout << endl << "   minimum Luminance  is: " << Lmin << endl;
cout << endl << "...luminance ratio is: " << LRATIO;

if (LRATIO > CRATIO) {
    cout << endl << "...luminance ratio is: " << LRATIO;
    cout << endl << "...this is too high, ending..." << '\a';
    return(0);
}

cout << endl << "...luminance can be corrected :)" << endl;

///______ CREATE RANDOM VALUES BETWEEN 0 & 1

  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution <double> distribution(0.0,1.0);

  for (int i=0; i<C; ++i) {
    double number = distribution(generator);
    RND.push_back(number);
  }

cout << endl << "...random values created" << endl;


///_______ process & export to PBM

ofstream output_file("./wall.pbm");

output_file << "P1" << "\n" << colo << " " << lines << "\n"; /// PBM HEADER

cout << endl << "...file header written" << endl;
cout << endl << "...computing";

int CELLS   = C;  // copy the amount of cells
int LINEW   = colo;
int PERCENT = 100;

    while (CELLS > 0) {
        while (LINEW > 0) {

            Z    = Lmin/CSV.front();        /// processing calculus
            X    = (NBK - Z)/(NBK - NW);
            aBK  = (1 - X);
            vRND = RND.front();


                            if (aBK > (vRND)) {
                                IO = 1;
                            }
                            else {
                                IO = 0;
                            }


            LINEW   = LINEW - 1;
            CELLS   = CELLS - 1;
            PERCENT = PERCENT - CELLS / C;

            output_file << IO << "\n";
            //cout << ERR << " "; /// fancy...

            CSV.erase(CSV.begin());
            RND.erase(RND.begin());
            }

        LINEW = colo;
    }


cout << endl << "...computing done" << endl;
cout << "...file written";

output_file.close();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: You might try OpenCV: http://opencv.org/

Answer (score 2):

Check out lib tiff.  OpenCV just uses lib tiff as well.

http://www.libtiff.org/

Comment: Hi, thanks but I couldn't find a simple example of using libtiff to load a greyscale tiff file in a `vector` or a `deque`, and about how to push the horizontal/vertical sizes in `int` variables!

Comment: TIFF is a complex format (too complex), it gives loads and loads of options if you are writing images but that makes reading images very difficult because you have to deal with all the options. If you want to read TIFF directly you are going to have to spend some time understanding all the details of the TIFF format.